# Error when using BeautifulSoup to get information from a html table

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to get information from the table within a HTML document and put in a dataframe. I've written the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
import pandas as pd

filename = input('Please enter HTML filename: ')


with open(filename, encoding = "UTF-8") as f_input:
    html = f_input.read()

f = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")


table = f.find_all("table")

n_columns = 0
n_rows = 0
column_names = []

for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    td_tags = row.find_all('td')
    if len(td_tags)>0:
    n_rows+=1
    if n_columns == 0:
       n_columns = len(td_tags)

th_tags = row.find_all('th')
if len(th_tags) > 0 and len(column_names) ==0:
    for th in th_tags:
        column_names.append(th.get_text())

if len(column_names) > 0 and len(column_names) != n_columns:
    raise Exception("Column titles do not match the number of columns")

columns = column_names if len(column_names)> 0 else range(0,n_columns)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns,
                 index=range(0,n_rows))
row_marker = 0
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    column_marker = 0
    columns = row.find_all('td')
    for column in columns:
        df.iat[row_marker,column_marker] = column.get_text()
        column_marker += 1
    if len(columns)>0:
        row_marker += 1
    for col in df:
        try:
            df[col]=df[col].astype(float)
        except ValueError:
            pass
return df
```

and it comes up with the following error:

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

I've read around, and I still don't understand what I am doing wrong. I don't think I should be using `find()`. Can anyone help explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your error comes from these lines:
    table = f.find_all("table")
     ... 
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):

Note that table is now a set (kind of like a list in some ways) of elements that have table in them. If there's only one table, you can access it with table[0] or by using find instead of find_all in the first call. 
If there's more than one table in the page, or your table may not be the first one, you might want to dig deeper in the set and see if your table has something that uniquely identifies it.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in this line `th_tags = row.find_all('th')`. `row` is not defined because it is out of the upper for loop.

Comment: This is also a bug, however it's probably not the one that's causing that error message